# Verificación de email Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

Estoy queriendo enviar el email para verificación y no lo envía, lo que tengo es:

dentro de las rutas web agregue:

> // Email Verification Routes...
>
> Route::get('email/verify',
>   'Auth\VerificationController@show')->name('verification.notice');
>   Route::get('email/verify/{id}',
>   'Auth\VerificationController@verify')->name('verification.verify');
>   Route::get('email/resend',
>   'Auth\VerificationController@resend')->name('verification.resend');

El model User que se encuentra dentro de APP lo movi a

> namespace App\FinDra\Entities\User;

lo renombre a UserModel y le agregué

> implements MustVerifyEmail

Dentro de config/auth.php

le cambie User por UserModel

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => \App\FinDra\Entities\User\UserModel::class,
    ],

],
```

aun despues de todo esto, al momento de registar un Usuario no envia el email

Comment: deberias verte la documentacion https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/verification

Comment: Realiza pruebas aisladas, donde por ejemplo solo envíes un correo, otra donde verifiques si realmente esta llegando a las rutas y así.

Answer (score 0):

en Laravel 5,8 eso ya no es necesario. Ahora es más simple.

Según la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/verification) lo que hay que hacer es:

1. Agregar `implements MustVerifyEmail` en el modelo `User`. Quedando así

   `class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail`
2. Importar el `MustVerifyEmail` quedando así:

   use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
3. Cambiar las rutas de login y registro por: `Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);`
4. Agregar el Middleware a la ruta:

   Route::get('profile', function () {
     // Solamente quienes hayan verificado su email podrán ingresar a esta ruta
   })->middleware('verified');
5. Por último, modificas la vista que está en `resources/views/auth/verify.blade.php`

Sobra decir que puedes manejar el Middleware a través del controlador. Saludos!

Comment: considera que aunque lo que aportas puede ser válido, si el proyecto no se puede migrar de una versión a otra, entonces la respuesta se debe adaptar a la necesidad y no al revés.